# Setting up Jquery Mobile for Phone Gap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am looking to setup jquery mobile with phone gap and perform a very simple task to see if it is working. This is what I have so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).on('pageinit', function(){
            $("#geolocation").html("Hey World");
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to change the contents of the p tag to "Hey World". I am very new to Phone Gap. Any advice would be great.

Comment: Have you also loaded jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a number of references in your head section:

1. jQuery Mobile CSS file
2. jQuery JS file

You also need to check the deviceready event for PhoneGap, unless you've done that on a page that was loaded by PhoneGap earlier. For example:

```
$(document).on("deviceready", function()
{
    // phonegap ready
}
```